py script using openpyxl not working when called form an html page
I'm a bit stuck! One of the great advantages of python is its capability to use libraries like openpyxl with a great deal of functions pp...
I created a py script like this:
Script: Create_New_WB.py (which works fine while testing it directly!)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook 
wb = Workbook() # create wb 
ws1 = wb.active # load sheet
ws1.title = "TestSheet"
ws2 = wb.create_sheet("TS 03") # creates additional sheet at the end
ws3 = wb.create_sheet("TS 02", -1) # creates additional sheet just before the last one



wb.save("./DATA/New_WB.xlsx") # saves new WB 
print("Finished")


HTML page: index.html (which calls the script above but ends up with error)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>

        <!-- Recommended meta tags -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- PyScript CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.3.2/core.css">

        <!-- This script tag bootstraps PyScript -->
        <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.3.2/core.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <py-env> 
        - openpyxl
    </py-env>
    <script type="py" src="./SCRIPTS/Create_New_WB.py" config="./SCRIPTS/pyscript.json"     terminal></script>
 </body>
 </html>`


 ERROR: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 44] No such file or directory: './DATA/New_WB.xlsx
 (index.html launched with Live Server / Visual Studio Code)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your support!

There's so much outdated here and it seems you aren't reading anything about using local files with pyscript and then implementing that. As a place to start, please look into how you now specify packages in the <py-config> section, see about this here and references therein. Start reading about using files here and in the linked references. You may also wish to see my comments in reply to the original post there. The older [[fetch]] example is here.

Thanks a lot Wayne, sorry but I just started .....

That's fine; however, then it is important to start with the very latest official stuff from pyscript as it is in very active development & the project changes fast.

Sure, that‘s what I also realised eventually….! Thanks again!
